# Use onclick method in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, onclick

I am making a website in which the login page has a button that is not setup as a button and it needs to call a function.  I add the:

```
onclick="signin()"
```

to the code on line 216. (see code here: http://pastebin.com/Uq2nfWTQ)

I have tried adding the function below the div's and on a main.js file.  Neither are working.  Where should I put the function so that the button actually works?  Also, the function is a redirect to a different page, so would I do that with:

```
window.location = "PUT LOCATION HERE"
```

Comment: The function should be in a `<script>` block, and it can be anywhere you want.

Comment: If you want more help, you need to post what you actually tried. Don't post a link, create a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and put it in the question.

Comment: @Barmar I put a <script> function signin() {  } </script> and the stuff inside it still doesn't work.

Comment: You need to post what you did. You obviously did it wrong, but we can't tell if you just describe instead of showing.

Comment: Can't see the `<script>` block in your code. If you did place it, then your function might have an error... Place the block, call the function and check what your console says.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the bare minimum of what you're describing:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script>
        function signin() {
            console.log("Hello, I work!");
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="javascript:void(0);" method="get">
        <input type="submit" value="Sign In" onclick="signin()">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comparing that to your paste bin, you don't have a `signin` function anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Thus is an example

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the button to go to signin page.</p>

<button onclick="signin()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function signin() {
    location.href = 'signin.php';

}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

Some people have JavaScript disabled or hampered for various reasons; making a web page that *requires* JavaScript just to go to another page is super irritating for those people!  (I am one of them.)

Plus, JavaScript-based navigation is never as useful as regular links.  You can middle-click normal links to open them in a new tab, for example, and I do this all the time; it breaks on JavaScript-powered "fake" links, because the page's code can't run in the new tab.  In general, using JavaScript to emulate an existing browser feature is a poor idea.

So if navigation is all you're doing, just make a regular link with an `<a>` and style it with CSS to *look* like a button.  A good (albeit ugly) start:

```
a#signin-button {
    display: inline-block;
    background: lightgray;
    border: 1px outset gray;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

OR, make it a plain submit button.  (Not recommended as much, since you can't do as much with a submit button — e.g., middle-click to open in a new tab doesn't work.)

```
<form action="signin.html" method="GET">
    <input type="submit" value="Sign In">
</form>
```

Comment: I'd think it's pretty obvious that what the OP's asking is part of a process. If someone is having trouble trying to calculate `var etc = 3 + 4`, don't answer "Just write `etc = 7`"

Comment: all i have to go on is what the OP says!  it's entirely plausible that someone might wind up on this train of thought just because they want a button to do navigation.  see [the XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: though from a closer glance at the pastebin, this is for an actual login _form_, which means none of these answers are really helpful since they don't deal with the form fields.  so i have no idea what OP is actually trying to do.